# Google Apps Script - Change the background color of a cell Row (0), change the font style in Row (1)

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to change the 1st cell backgroundcolor and 2nd cell font style but cannot seems to get it.

```html
function insertHeading1(){
  var heading1Style = {};
  heading1Style[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_FAMILY] = 'Calibri';
  heading1Style[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = 18;
  heading1Style[DocumentApp.Attribute.HORIZONTAL_ALIGNMENT] = DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.LEFT;
  heading1Style[DocumentApp.Attribute.LINE_SPACING] = 1;
  
  var cells = [
  ['#1c3a69', 'HEADING 1, CALIBRI, 18PT, BOLD, LEFT ALIGNED, ALL CAPS, SINGLE SPACING, NO SPACE BEFORE AND AFTER PARAGRAPH'],
  ];

  var tableRow1 = body.appendTable(cells);
  tableRow1.getCell(0,0).editAsText()
  .setBackgroundColor(0,1,'#1c3a69');
  tableRow1.getCell(0,1).editAsText
  .apply(heading1Style);
}
```

No errors, not sure what went wrong.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your script, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var tableRow1 = body.appendTable(cells);
tableRow1.getCell(0,0).editAsText()
.setBackgroundColor(0,1,'#1c3a69');
tableRow1.getCell(0,1).editAsText
.apply(heading1Style);
```

#### To:

```
tableRow1.setColumnWidth(0, 100);
tableRow1.getCell(0, 0).setBackgroundColor('#1c3a69');
tableRow1.getCell(0, 1).editAsText().setAttributes(heading1Style);
```

Or, if you want to set the font color of 1st cell to `#ffffff`, how about the following modification?

```
tableRow1.setColumnWidth(0, 100);
tableRow1.getCell(0, 0).setBackgroundColor('#1c3a69').editAsText().setForegroundColor("#ffffff");
tableRow1.getCell(0, 1).editAsText().setAttributes(heading1Style);
```

- In this modification, your `heading1Style` is used. And, from your showing expected situation, in order to set the column width, `tableRow1.setColumnWidth(0, 100)` is used.
- If you want to set `heading1Style` to the 1st cell, please modify to `tableRow1.getCell(0, 0).setBackgroundColor('#1c3a69').editAsText().setAttributes(heading1Style)` or `tableRow1.getCell(0, 0).setBackgroundColor('#1c3a69').editAsText().setForegroundColor("#ffffff").setAttributes(heading1Style)`.

#### References:

- [setBackgroundColor(color)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/table-cell#setbackgroundcolorcolor)
- [editAsText()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/table-cell#editastext)

Comment: thanks @Tanaike, that works fine. tableRow1.setColumnWidth(0, 100); but how do I change the column width in cell1 to be at certain point? e.g. 10?   Also trying to make that heading1 into the heading1Style but seems heading1 is for paragraph.

Comment: ok, I solved the column width.  Now is the Heading1.   heading1Style[DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD] = true;
  heading1Style[DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading] = DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING1;  No error running but when I load into Google Doc, there is an error.  Exception: Unexpected error while getting the method or property setAttributes on object DocumentApp.Text.

Comment: @user1787756 Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Comment: thanks for your help.  But I faced 2 more issue is how do I set the heading1 for tableRow1.getCell(0, 1).editAsText().setAttributes(heading1Style); and also the spacing when checked is 1.15 instead of value set as 1, heading1Style[DocumentApp.Attribute.LINE_SPACING] = 1;   Should I open a new thread or can reply here?

Comment: @user1787756 Thank you for replying. About your new question, I would like to support you. So, in this case, I would like to recommend posting it as a new question. At that time, when you add more information, it will help understand your new question.

Comment: Sure, appreciate your help and advise. :)